# How to get Hudson to show complete selenium report?

Tags: java, selenium, hudson

Our Hudson installation shows a very spartan version of the Selenium report:

```
Selenium Report Result
numTestPasses   2
numTestFailures 0
```

I've understood that it should be possible to view full reports via Hudson, and also track development of the tests. But how?

Comment: Can you give us more details? 

  - do you use hudsons selenium plugin?
  - do you call selenium from ant/maven?

Comment: Yes, selenium plugin is installed to Hudson. Selenium is ran using selenium-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

We configured Hudson to run Selenium through an Ant task.  Then we added a post-build action to "Publish JUnit test result report."  With this setup we can see each failed test name along with how long each test took and the ability to drill down into all the tests to see specifics.

You may be able to just add that post build action to your project using the Selenium plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits in your environment: I'm running selenium-rc via JUnit (and phpunit) test cases using ant in a Hudson freestyle Project.
Hudson collects and publishes JUnit and via xUnit Plugin various other test results in an optional post build step.

Maybe you just need to find out where the build process stores the actual xml report and instruct hudson to publish it?

Answer (score 0):

I run Selenium tests in Hudson using this [plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Seleniumhq+Plugin). It runs my Selenium tests and publishes detailed test reports. Very easy to configure, maybe not perfect if you have a lot of test suites to execute.

Comment: i have given relative path of my TestResult.html file to "Publish Selenium Report" input, but when i check Console Output it take that as "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumtest\usr\local\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\seleniumtest\selenium-html\TestResult.html", Note rootpath is added two times!!!! I don't know what to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

We use the SeleniumHQ plugin. The results are saved in the workspace (this is done in the project config by using "Publish Selenium Report"). You can save the build reports by using "Archive the artifacts" in project config.

Answer (score 0):

We have written the Selenium tests as normal JUnit tests, which gets executed with the rest of the tests, so the reports are embeded i the junit test report generated by hudson.